# Chrome: Export Highcharts into svg format for certain charts getting error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I export the same highcharts into SVG in IE, it is working expected but when I try in chrome, I am getting the error shown below.

"*error on line 1 at column 12202: xmlParseEntityRef: no name*"

Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is the SVG export part of my code:

```
renderedChart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
if (type === 'svg') {
     renderedChart.exportChart({
                   'type': 'image/svg+xml'
                 }, {
                   title: {
                         style: {
                                 display: 'visible'
                                }
                           }
                });
   }
```

[image: For image, please click here]

Comment: can you describe the error ?

Comment: 'error on line 1 at column 12202: xmlParseEntityRef: no name' this is the error I am getting

Comment: this error occurs when you have syntax error in your xml

Comment: Hi Pooja Mgr, everything seems to work correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p6czo9mu/ Could you reproduce your problem in this example?

Comment: fixed my issue by adding attribute 'allowHTML': true
thank you all for the suggestions